# How do I mock a function in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-testing, python-unittest.mock

I expect the following call to `which_user` to return `self.user` no matter what is passed into it but it's behaving as if it is not mocked at all.

```
def test_user_can_retrieve_favs_using_impersonation(self):
        with mock.patch('impersonate.helpers.which_user', return_value=self.user):
            user = which_user(self.user2)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I imported `which_user` like so: `from impersonate.helpers import which_user` if that helps.

Comment: Mock where the function is imported to, not where it is imported from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mock function by its path to which it's imported.
For example, you use your function inside myapp's views. So you need to do it in following way:

```
with mock.patch('myapp.views.which_user', return_value=self.user):
        user = which_user(self.user2)
```

This is because it patches only variables defined in testable module, not patching original libraries and packages in the system or venv.